# Nested child GridView onrowedit error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using a `Gridview` inside another `GridView`.
I want to implement edit / update in child `Gridview`.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvChildGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                      onrowediting="gvChildGrid_RowEditing" >
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Template>
```

onrowedit for child gridview is like below

```
protected void gvChildGrid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
  gvChildGrid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
  BindData();
}
```

This is showing error

*gvChildGrid doesnot exist in current context .*

Please help how to implement edit /Update child gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change your code like this

```
protected void gvChildGrid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

    ((GridView)sender).EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindData();

}
```

**UPDATE**
in runtime you cann't get nested gridview by name, because it inside template field, so you can get it from `sender` object